# Forced closed only when put alphabetical string in edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

So, I make a checker if an id is in the database or not, the id is in numerical string, the type in database is char(6) though.

So this is my code

```
public class input extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.input);

        final EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String nopel = edittext.getText().toString();               

                if(nopel.length() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nopel", nopel));

                    JSON json_dp = new JSON();
                    JSONObject jobj_dp = json_dp.getJSON("http://10.0.2.2/KP/pdam/nopel.php", pairs);

                    try {
                        if(jobj_dp.getInt("row") == 0){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            String snopel = jobj_dp.getString("nopel");
                            String snama = jobj_dp.getString("nama");
                            String salamat = jobj_dp.getString("alamat");
                            String sgolongan = jobj_dp.getString("golongan");

                            Intent i = new Intent(input.this, list.class);
                            i.putExtra("nopel", snopel);
                            i.putExtra("nama", snama);
                            i.putExtra("alamat", salamat);
                            i.putExtra("golongan", sgolongan);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                   
                }
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

the first check is to check if an input is null, it's going right for now, the second check is to check if an id in the database, and it's the problem. When I try some id in numerical value like "0001" or "02013" it's fine, and can run. but when I just got to put "abushd" it forced close. anyone know why I got this?

This is the list.class

```
public class list extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String nopel = i.getStringExtra("nopel");
        String nama = i.getStringExtra("nama");
        String alamat = i.getStringExtra("alamat");
        String golongan = i.getStringExtra("golongan");

        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView t2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        t1.setText(nopel);
        t2.setText(nama);
        t3.setText(alamat);
        t4.setText(golongan);
    }
}
```

and this is what is there on logcat

```
06-28 16:14:18.244: W/KeyCharacterMap(253): No keyboard for id 0
06-28 16:14:18.254: W/KeyCharacterMap(253): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-28 16:14:22.394: D/AndroidRuntime(253): Shutting down VM
06-28 16:14:22.404: W/dalvikvm(253): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
06-28 16:14:22.404: E/AndroidRuntime(253): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at pdam.tirta.raharja.input$1.onClick(input.java:47)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-28 16:14:22.414: E/AndroidRuntime(253):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 16:14:22.424: I/dalvikvm(253): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
06-28 16:14:22.424: E/dalvikvm(253): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: Please add stack trace from mlogcat

Comment: Shall we go through this code to suggest solution? Your question and this code are not at all related!!

Comment: may be for not valid number "abushd" you are getting jobj_dp null and jobj_dp.getInt("row") will throw error then.. can try with if(null!=jobj_dp) just after try ...

Comment: What line is line 47 in input.java?

Comment: i think it's this

`if(jobj_dp.getInt("row") == 0)`

Comment: I do what Dheeresh Singh and it worked wonderfully, I thank you all guys that willing to help me :D

Answer (score 1):

You're using `jobj_dp.getInt("row")`.
Of course if it will crash if the value contained in "row" is not an integer.

Use `getString()` instead.